# F# higher-order functions on discrete unions

Tags: f#

I am trying to write a REST client in F# that uses strongly-typed values to define resource "signatures". I have decided to use discrete unions to represent the signature as a list of optional arguments. I am planning on providing a generic way to convert the parameter value to a list of tuples that represent the key/value pairs that will be used to create the request. This is a learning exercise so I am trying to use idomatic F#.

I've gotten stuck, trying to define two different discrete unions which have similar signatures. Is there a way for me to dynamically select the right pattern matching function at runtime?

```
type A =
    | First of string
    | Second of string

type B =
    | First of string
    | Second of string
    | Third of string

let createA f s =
    [A.First f; A.Second s;]

let createB f s t =
    [B.First f; B.Second s; B.Third t]

let toParamA elem =
    match elem with
    | A.First f -> "First", f
    | A.Second s -> "Second", s

let toParamB elem =
    match elem with
    | B.First f -> "First", f
    | B.Second s -> "Second", s
    | B.Third t -> "Third", t

let rec toParam f state args =
    match args with
    | [] -> state
    | head::tail -> 
        let state' = (f head)::state
        toParam f state' tail

let argA = createA "one" "two"
let argB = createB "one" "two" "three"

let resultA = argA |> toParam toParamA []
let resultB = argB |> toParam toParamB []
```

The result is currently correct, I'm just not happy with the API:

```
val resultA : (string * string) list = [("Second", "two"); ("First", "one")]
val resultB : (string * string) list = [("Third", "three"); ("Second", "two"); ("First", "one")]
```

**UPDATE:**

The question was asked what would I like the call to look like?

```
let resultA = argA |> toParam []
```

Then toParam would figure out whether to call toParamA or toParamB.

I think I've realized my original approach works fine for the current situation. However, I'd still be interested to know if my pseudo-code is possible.

Comment: Why exactly are you not happy with the API? What would you envision it to be? Also: they're called _discriminated_ unions, not _discrete_.

Comment: As I said I'd like to be able to select the mapping dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Let me amend my last comment: Can you provide a hypothetical use case for the API that you _want_? (as opposed to what you've been able to make) And by use case I mean some code. Even if it's pseudocode.

Comment: I think you may be right. After stepping back I think this may be the right level of abstraction. As it stands, the caller will construct the request and pass it to a method that's expecting a specificly typed list of unions (A or B in this case). So it has the information it needs to call paramA or paramB. This was the first time I learned that overloading isn't supported. I had been expecting to just be able to call an overloaded function within toParam instead of passing toParamA or toParamB. That way I could just write: let resultA = argA |> toParam []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most vanilla F#-way would be to explicitly state for which API method you're constructing your parameter list:

```
type ApiArgs = ApiA of A list | ApiB of B list
```

And then you could conflate your `toParamA` and `toParamB` functions like this:

```
let toParam = function
| ApiA args ->
    let toParamA = function
    | A.First x -> "First", x
    | A.Second x -> "Second", x

    List.map toParamA args 
| ApiB args ->
    let toParamB = function
    | B.First x -> "First", x
    | B.Second x -> "Second", x
    | B.Third x -> "Third", x

    List.map toParamB args
```

I see two possibilities for improvement here. First, the code is too repetitive and boring. You probably can generate the code with a type provider for your API, or use reflection at run time to do the conversion.

Second, the polymorphic behavior of converting either `A` or `B` to `(string * string) list` happens at run time, but I think you can pull it off at compile time:

```
type X = X with
    static member ($) (_, args : A list) =
        let toParamA = function
        | A.First x -> "First", x
        | A.Second x -> "Second", x

        List.map toParamA args

    static member ($) (_, args : B list) =
        let toParamB = function
        | B.First x -> "First", x
        | B.Second x -> "Second", x
        | B.Third x -> "Third", x

        List.map toParamB args

let inline toParam' args = X $ args
```

If you inspect `toParam'`'s inferred type, it will look similar to this:

```
val inline toParam' :
  args: ^a ->  ^_arg3
    when (X or  ^a) : (static member ( $ ) : X *  ^a ->  ^_arg3)
```

(The `^a` notation is a so-called "hat type", read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx))

And then calling `toParam'` with arguments of different type yield correct results:

```
> toParam' (createA "one" "two");;
val it : (string * string) list = [("First", "one"); ("Second", "two")]
> toParam' (createB "1" "2" "3");;
val it : (string * string) list =
  [("First", "1"); ("Second", "2"); ("Third", "3")]
>
```

This technique is described in detail in [this blog](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/11/15/typeclasses-for-fsharp/), but I believe it is an outdated way to do it. For more inspiration, take a look at these projects: [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl), [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus), [Higher](https://github.com/palladin/higher).

Comment: There's a lot of good stuff in here - it'll take me a bit to digest it all, but I've already made several improvements thanks to your answer.